# Css Change Background color of a td on hover of an other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color of Product_image when i hover the whole Table name.
The result i am trying to achieve is when the table changes color on hover, the product image td to change also but with an other color.

I saw similar posts: [Make a div css change when hover an other div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878391/make-a-div-css-change-when-hover-an-other-div)

But didn't worked on me.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <table class="Tablename">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td class="Product_image"><div class="Product_image"><a title=""><img src=""></a></div></td>
    <td class="Product_name"><div class="Product_name"><a href=""</a></div></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Tablename:hover{ background-color:#fff}
 .Tablename:hover + .Product_image  {
     background-color:#21825B !important;
 }
```

I am trying to achieve this only with css.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what is that `+` for in CSS? and also your second `<a>` is not closed means missing `>`!

Comment: The i accidentically erased it when i remove the content of it to post it here.It's ok normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the + sign.  Its the adjacent sibling selector.  The div you want to change is a child of the table, not a sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `+` sign:

```
.Tablename:hover {
    background-color: #fff
}

.Tablename:hover .Product_image {
    background-color: #21825B !important;
}
```

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tRJv2/2/).

Explanation: The `+` sign selects only adjacent siblings. [See this small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRJv2/1/) to get an understanding of this selector.

Comment: You should remove the + too, not just say it :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing with my ul li structure. Here is the example

```
#main_nav.sf-menu li ul li:hover a{ color:#fff;}
```

so in your case it should

```
.Tablename:hover{ background-color:#fff}
 .Tablename:hover Product_image  {
     background-color:#21825B !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are very close to the right solution. Try this:
remove the "+" symbol and make the row like that:

```
.Tablename:hover td.Product_image  {
     background-color:#21825B !important;
 }
```

So you say: on table hover change the background color of the td with class "Product_image"
you even do not need the !important

Comment: it was is a part of some attempts i would remove it after fixing it. :). Thanks for the solution :D